# How long can I stay in Germany after I resign from my work before getting a blue card?

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card, overstay

I’ve been working in Berlin for 3 months and I have applied for a Blue card 3 weeks ago. I still didn’t receive the approval yet. However, I’m considering resigning from my current role before receiving the blue card.

Therefore, I would like to know how long I can stay in Germany after my last day of work. Or should I leave on my last day of work before midnight? Note that I’m a non-EU citizen. And I have a visa for 6 months, but the name of the company is written on the visa, so it’s valid as long as I will be working for them.

Answer (score 1):

It is nearly impossible to give an easy and short answer to this.

A blue card is valid 3 Month after the job has ended, but in the first 2 years you need yo ask for permission if you want to change your job with a blue card

http://www.bluecard-eu.de/eu-blue-card-germany/residence-act/bc.html

A quick research shows me that there are several types of visa but more important is, that your possibilities depend on your qualification, your financial situation, your nationality and also on your knowledge of the German language.

Sometimes it can be a problem, if you entered the country on a working visa basis and later you want to change it to a permanent status, as far as I understand the law. But I'm not an expert ...

You should seek assistance from an organisation like Caritas, IHK, sometimes at Universities  or if you can afford it, contact a lawyer who is specialized in "Ausländerrecht"

Edit:

After reading this http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html

and this:

[What are the permit implications of voluntarily leaving a job as a US citizen Blue Card-holder in Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8209/what-are-the-permit-implications-of-voluntarily-leaving-a-job-as-a-us-citizen-bl?rq=1)

(read his answer) I guess it can be an advantage not to have received the BC yet.
If you find a better job soon, it's maybe better to apply for a BC with the new job