# How long can I stay in Germany after quitting my Blue Card job?

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card

I am from a non-EU country and hold a German "Blue Card EU" which is tied to a job I had in Germany. I worked there for 1 year but stopped working there last week.

I am now in the process of applying for a Swiss working permit and I intend to move there and begin working there when that is finished. I was told that it could take more than 3 months though to get the working permit, which is kind of worrying because I am only allowed 90 visa-free days in the Schengen zone.

Therefore my question is: how long can I stay in Germany now that I have quit the job for which I had my Blue Card? Citizens of my country get 90 visa free days, so there's that, but do I get any "extra" time thanks to my blue card? It surely musn't expire as soon as I quit my job, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the permit implications of voluntarily leaving a job as a US citizen Blue Card-holder in Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8209/what-are-the-permit-implications-of-voluntarily-leaving-a-job-as-a-us-citizen-bl)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information (left employment after a period less than 18 or 24 months ; before regular contract ends), the following seams to apply:

> **[§51 Beendigung der Rechtmäßigkeit des Aufenthalts](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__51.html); Fortgeltung von Beschränkungen**
>
> (1) Der Aufenthaltstitel erlischt in folgenden Fällen:
>
> ...
>
> 2. Eintritt einer auflösenden Bedingung,

Since there is **no** further reference to *§51 (1) Nr. 2* (where exceptions are defined) , assume the residence permit ends when the employment ends.

This is a case where you should report the situation to the issuing authority (including your application in Switzerland) **as soon as possible**.